# How to web scrape data from a page where login is a popup box

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

I would like to scrape data off a webpage([urbanation.ca](http://urbanation.ca)) for which I have login credentials. My login allows me to download data in the form of excel sheets but that would take a really long time. That's why I would like to scrape data off of it.

Now, I do see a lot of posts where it tells you how to scrape it when the site asks you for login. But, in my case, the login is a button on the webpage which when clicked opens a popup window that asks for login credentials. How do I deal with this?

```
import requests
import re
r = requests.get('https://www.urbanation.ca', proxies={'http':'50.207.31.221:80'}).text

payload = {'name': 'username', 'pass': 'password'}
POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.urbanation.ca'
REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.urbanation.ca/urbanation/project/1/view'

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
    print(r.text)
```

I know that I don't have the right entry for the post_login_url variable because I don't know where to post my credentials.

Comment: I would edit the post and take out your login information first. It works lol.

Comment: Try the following: `POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.urbanation.ca/fp2018?destination=fp2018`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. As Stivan said in the comments, you should **really** consider removing your login information from the post.

```py
import requests

data = {
    'name': 'EMAIL HERE',
    'pass': 'PASSWORD HERE',
    'form_id': 'user_login_block',
    'op': 'login <span class="teal m1_arrow  arrow-right"></span>',
}
url = 'https://www.urbanation.ca/fp2018?destination=fp2018'
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
```